# What is Difference between store() and storeAs() function in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am new in laravel framework. I saw some of videos on youtube about file upload, in this videos some of developers using store() function and some of using storeAs() function. I Don't know difference ?? 
 **Can anyone know what is exact difference???**

Comment: https://www.5balloons.info/example-file-upload-validation-laravel-5-6/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**`store`** method will **generate a unique ID to serve as the file name**

```php
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store($path, $options);

// 03g5ugwvzajj0ckTVH5AlTvvZkgLFhvPhb3LbIGh.jpg
```

**`storeAs`** if you would not like a file name to be automatically assigned to your stored file, you may use the `storeAs` method, which receives the path, the file name, and the (optional) disk as its arguments:

```php
$path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs($path, $name, $options);

// $name
```

Comment: How about move? What's the differences?

Comment: @RayCoder the `move` method may be used to rename or move an existing file to a new location., but the `store` method on an uploaded file instance.